# WPF data binding - Display the Summary of collection in multiple labels

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF application with one `ListBox` and `ListView`.
`ListView` displays the list of Customers, 
and `ListBox` contains the hard-coded Customer type value - *(Regular/Silver/Platinum/gold/)*

If the user selects the Gold in `ListBox`, I filter the list view using the below code:

```
var view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myList.ItemsSource);
view.Filter= item => true;
```

It works fine, but at any point of time , I need to display the summary of the customer data for each category/status in a `Label`, for example the output should look like this

```
Platinum : 15
Gold     : 25
Silver   : 37
Regular  : 13
Total    : 90
```

My data source is

```
public ObservableCollection<Customer> customer { get; set; }
```

Any body have idea how to bind this data

Please let me know if anybody have solution/ worked on similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = "";
foreach (string val in myList.ItemsSource)
{
   result += val + " : " + CollectionViewSource.Cast[val].Count + "\r\n";
}
```

After that you can bind the "result" with a TextBlock.

Comment: thanks @benoît I want to bind this on XAML page, so that when the collection get changed (add/Remove/ customer status changed), the summary will get auto refreshed

Comment: Yep.Basically when the collection changed just recalculate result. Result should be a property using OnPropertyChanged on the set.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand about customer's type, it will be like this:

Xaml:

```
<Label Content="{Binding PlatinumCount}"/>
<Label Content="{Binding GoldCount}"/>
...
```

Code-behind:

```
public int PlatinumCount => customer.Count(x => x.Type == "Platinum");
public int GoldCount => customer.Count(x => x.Type == "Gold");
...
```

And somewhere in your code initialization:

```
customer.CollectionChanged += (o, args) => 
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("PlatinumCount");
        OnPropertyChanged("GoldCount");
    };
```

Of course, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class.